# Prevent force close when error happens

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-edittext, forceclose

I have below code.
When the edit text throws "String not found" error it force-closes.
What can I do to prevent it? For example using a Toast notification?

```
    public void OnClImgBtSearch(View v)
{
    ImageButton ImgBtSearch=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtSearch);
    EditText EditTextGhavaninShow=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextGhavaninShow);
    EditText EditTextGhavaninSearch=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextGhavaninSearch);

    String StrEditText =EditTextGhavaninSearch.getText().toString();


    //(EditTextGhavaninShow.getText().toString().contains(StrEditText))

    String s = EditTextGhavaninShow.getText().toString();
    try{
    if(EditTextGhavaninShow.getText().toString().contains(StrEditText));
    {
    int position = s.indexOf(StrEditText);              // where C is your character to be searched
    int Lastlen=s.lastIndexOf(StrEditText);
    int FirstLen=s.indexOf(StrEditText);
    EditTextGhavaninShow.setSelection(FirstLen,Lastlen);
    }}
    catch (TypeNotPresentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "عبارت مورد نظر یافت نشد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: is there any way to select or highlight all simlare word that user serched in edittext?

Comment: I think this is a different question and it is better that you post a new question in SO

Comment: the only way to not force close the app when error happens is catch the error and handle it.

Comment: sorry your site not allow me to post several question!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent your app crash with any kind of error you should use `Exception` class:

```
try{
    if(EditTextGhavaninShow.getText().toString().contains(StrEditText)){
        int position = s.indexOf(StrEditText); // where C is your character to be searched
        int Lastlen=s.lastIndexOf(StrEditText);
        int FirstLen=s.indexOf(StrEditText);
        EditTextGhavaninShow.setSelection(FirstLen,Lastlen);
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "عبارت مورد نظر یافت نشد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even though It's not a good solution, you should manage your app in a way that don't crash in every single scenario.

Comment: is there any why to highlight or select the word that user search for it in edittext?

Comment: You could try with android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

Comment: no i want to select or highlight just the word that user inter in EditTextGhavaninSearch and search for it.